# Taylor series of cos x expansion in python

Tags: python, taylor-series

I want to calculate the summation of cosx series (while keeping the x in radian). This is the code i created:

```
import math
def cosine(x,n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, n+1):
        sum += ((-1) ** i) * (x**(2*i)/math.factorial(2*i))
    return sum
```

and I checked it using `math.cos()` .
It works just fine when I tried out small numbers:

```
print("Result: ", cosine(25, 1000))
print(math.cos(25))
```

the output:

> `Result:  0.991203540954667`  `0.9912028118634736`

The number is still similar. But when I tried a bigger number, i.e 40, it just returns a whole different value.

> `Result:  1.2101433786727471`  `-0.6669380616522619`

Anyone got any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error term for a Taylor expansion increases the further you are from the point expanded about (in this case, `x_0 = 0`). To reduce the error, exploit the periodicity and symmetry by only evaluating within the interval `[0, 2 * pi]`:

```
def cosine(x, n):
    x = x % (2 * pi)
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        total += ((-1) ** i) * (x**(2*i) / math.factorial(2*i))
    return total
```

This can be further improved to `[0, pi/2]`:

```
def cosine(x, n):
    x = x % (2 * pi)
    if x > pi:
        x = abs(x - 2 * pi)
    if x > pi / 2:
        return -cosine(pi - x, n)
    total = 0
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        total += ((-1) ** i) * (x**(2*i) / math.factorial(2*i))
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the answer you got, this Taylor series converges regardless of how large the argument is. The factorial in the terms' denominators eventually drives the terms to 0.

But *before* the factorial portion dominates, terms can get larger and larger in absolute value. Native floating point doesn't have enough bits of precision to keep enough information for the low-order bits to survive.

Here's a way that doesn't lose any bits of precision. It's not practical because it's slow. Trust me when I tell you that it typically takes years of experience to learn how to write practical, fast, high-quality math libraries.

```py
def mycos(x, nbits=100):
    from fractions import Fraction
    x2 = - Fraction(x) ** 2
    i = 0
    ntries = 0
    total = term = Fraction(1)
    while True:
        ntries += 1
        term = term * x2 / ((i+1) * (i+2))
        i += 2
        total += term
        if (total // term).bit_length() > nbits:
            break
    print("converged to >=", nbits, "bits in", ntries, "steps")
    return total
```

and then your examples:

```
>>> mycos(25)
converged to >= 100 bits in 60 steps
Fraction(177990265631575526901628601372315751766446600474817729598222950654891626294219622069090604398951917221057277891721367319419730580721270980180746700236766890453804854224688235663001, 179569976498504495450560473003158183053487302118823494306831203428122565348395374375382001784940465248260677204774780370309486592538808596156541689164857386103160689754560975077376)
>>> float(_)
0.9912028118634736
>>> mycos(40)
converged to >= 100 bits in 82 steps
Fraction(-41233919211296161511135381283308676089648279169136751860454289528820133116589076773613997242520904406094665861260732939711116309156993591792484104028113938044669594105655847220120785239949370429999292710446188633097549, 61825710035417531603549955214086485841025011572115538227516711699374454340823156388422475359453342009385198763106309156353690402915353642606997057282914587362557451641312842461463803518046090463931513882368034080863251)
>>> float(_)
-0.6669380616522619
```

Things to note:

- The full-precision results require lots of bits.
- Rounded back to float, they identically match what you got from `math.cos()`.
- It doesn't require anywhere near 1000 steps to converge.